# How to run this project as a jar file?

Tags: java, jar, javacpp

Can you make a jar file out of this project that runs with no initializererror?

Project here.
https://github.com/piersy/BasicTesseractExample

I've tried using jarsplice to splice the project jar with the tesseract & javacpp jars and I get this initializer error, when running the jar in the command prompt. I don't know if jarsplice is even required but that was my effort.

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\JavaWorkspace>java -jar fatOCR.jar Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at BasicTesseractExampleTest.givenTessBaseApi_whenImageOcrd_thenTextDisplayed(BasicTesseractExampleTest.java:14)
        at runOCR.main(runOCR.java:7) Caused by: java.lang.ArrayStoreException: sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseArray(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.createAnnotationData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.annotationData(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.ClassProperties.load(ClassProperties.java:128)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadProperties(Loader.java:203)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:372)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:354)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3422)
        ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can run this project because it contains only tests (1 test in this case) and does not contain the *main* method.

Comment: OK, I linked that initial project because it's easier. I have tried the main method and that is how I got to that command prompt error. Thanks.